# I have a AS3 class which extends movieClip with a dynamic image, how to make this image draggable?

Tags: actionscript-3, draggable, loader, movieclip

I need to make an item draggable (dragable?) Sorry if my terminology is not right!

I have a class where I will store variable and do calculations:

```
package Classes
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.*;

    public class PrintItem extends MovieClip
    {     
        public var imageLoader:Loader;

        public function PrintItem()
        {

        }

        public function loadImage(url:String):void
        {
            imageLoader = new Loader();
            imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(url));
        }
    }
}
```

I create a new instance of the class, I pass it an URL in loadImage and I add it to the canvas like this:

```
var myItem:PrintItem = new PrintItem();
myItem.loadImage("pic.jpg");
this.addChild(myItem.imageLoader);
myItem.imageLoader.x = 50;
myItem.imageLoader.y = 50;
myItem.imageLoader.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickUp);
myItem.imageLoader.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropIt);
```

But there I am stuck. I need to make this item draggable and write the pickUp and dropIt functions. event.target.startDrag(false); doesn't work (Loader isn't draggable) and event.target.parent.startDrag(false); doesn't work as the whole stage becomes draggable! HELP! Is it because only the Loader is added to the stage?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I know it has only been a few minutes, but I have found the answer. Writing it down here cleared it in my head. Here's what worked for me in case it helps anybody else:

First, I added the Loader image as a child to the class like this:

```
public function loadImage(url:String):void
{
    imageLoader = new Loader();
    imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(url));
    this.addChild(imageLoader); // IMPORTANT!
    this.mouseChildren = false;
    this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickUp);
    this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropIt);
}
```

And then I only had to add the class to the stage, not the loader:

```
this.addChild(myItem);
```

Back to the class, I added this:

```
public function pickUp(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  trace("Pickup");
  this.startDrag(false);
}
public function dropIt(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  this.stopDrag();
  trace("X = " + event.target.x + " Y = " + event.target.y); // Just to help me
}
```

Et voila! It worked!

Comment: you will find that there will be an issue whereby if you drag quickly and release, that dropIt will not be fired since you have released off the imageLoader. To fix this, the listener for dropIt should be listening at the stage level. It should do this in your pickUp function. Don't forget to remove it from your dropIt function.